# UK Visa: can my mother-in-law be our sponsor?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

My wife and I are applying for UK visitor visa to sit PLAB 2 exam in the UK and we are applying from Iraq.

We are both working as medical doctors and we will leave our eight months child back home.

We want to sit the exam as soon as possible but our bank statements might not be for six months But they contain more than $7000 each

We want to ask if we can use my mother-in-law’s bank statement as a sponsor.

She is 60 years old retired and Has good amount of money in her bank account, She does not have a regular job or a regular income, the source of her money is a sold property which she can provide an evidence for it (selling contract). She can provide a six month bank statement from her account but there are a few transactions during these six months and most of them are withdraws.

Given her circumstances above, can she be a valid sponsor for both of us or at least one of us?

Comment: This should tell you a lot about why _your_ bank statements are needed: [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) (Hint: It's not the final balance that matters, it's the history.) Also, please see the "Sponsorship" section here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/92122/67978 to understand that using a sponsor often makes an application weaker instead of stronger.

Comment: Also, you say you want to sit the exam as soon as possible. Be prepared to provide a bulletproof justification for that in the application, as being in a hurry or even desperate to get into the UK can be seen as a red flag.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use your mother-in-law as a sponsor.

**But** you will still have to provide your own bank statements, and not being able to do so for all the required months is a problem. Read the linked answer for more information.

You would be wise to consider waiting until you have stable finances and the bank statements to prove it.